# "quickly submitubuntu" doesn't install app in /opt directory

Tags: application-development, quickly

According to the Ubuntu App Showdown Rules (http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/rules/), "Quickly installs your app to /opt for you when you run quickly submitubuntu." However there's nothing in the /opt directory after running "quickly submitubuntu". What can I do?

Edit: result of running "quickly submitubuntu"

```
Launchpad connection is ok
................Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
.....pushing to launchpad
.............................Checking signature on .changes
gpg: Signature made Mon 25 Jun 2012 03:34:15 PM EDT using RSA key ID 397C7008
gpg: Good signature from "David Pan <David Pan>"
Good signature on ../indicator-launchertoggle_12.06.3_source.changes.
Checking signature on .dsc
gpg: Signature made Mon 25 Jun 2012 03:34:15 PM EDT using RSA key ID 397C7008
gpg: Good signature from "David Pan <David Pan>"
Good signature on ../indicator-launchertoggle_12.06.3.dsc.
Uploading to ppa (via ftp to ppa.launchpad.net):
  Uploading indicator-launchertoggle_12.06.3.dsc: done.
  Uploading indicator-launchertoggle_12.06.3.tar.gz: done.  
  Uploading indicator-launchertoggle_12.06.3_source.changes: done.
Successfully uploaded packages.
Calling GPG to create tarball signature...
indicator-launchertoggle 12.06.3 released and submitted to ubuntu. Wait for half an hour and have look at https://launchpad.net/~napdivad/+archive/ppa.
Then your application will be reviewed by the application review board.
```

Comment: Before running quickly submitubuntu, you should: create your account
and a project page on http://launchpad.net.
You also have to add a PPA to your launchpad account. was that done and what was the result of  `quickly submitubuntu`

Comment: yes I did; the result is above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `quickly package --extras` in order to get the packaging files to target /opt.

Answer (score 1):

The `quickly submitubuntu` command will create a package that installs in `/opt` and will upload it to a public PPA of your choice in Launchpad.

You will then need to **install** that package, which is the step you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe quickly automatically configures the deb to install in /opt, but doesn't actually install it in /opt.